# Django app spam prevention

Tags: django, apache

we have a Django web application running on Ubuntu/Apache.  Lately, we've had a lot of issues with high volume spamming (comments, registrations, user contributed content, etc.).

We have [CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) security in place, but am wondering what steps others have taken to curb this (ip table restrictions, Apache modules, captchas, etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what other posters already written, you can use [akismet](http://akismet.com) or [mollom](http://mollom.com/) services. For both exist Python libraries on pypi, respectively [akismet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/akismet) and [PyMollom](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMollom). You can see how they get integrated in a Django project [here](https://github.com/mikery/django-akismet) (akismet example) and [here](http://django-blog-zinnia.com/api/zinnia.spam_checker.backends.mollom-pysrc.html) (mollom example).

If you instead don't want to rely on external services consider to use a captcha application for Django. Personally I used [Django Simple Captcha](http://code.google.com/p/django-simple-captcha/) and was happy with it, it's very customizable and easy to install. It also supports audio captcha. [This bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/pdina/django-captcha-contact-form) contains a simple Django project showing how to captcha protect a classic contact form using Django Simple Captcha.

Also I'm not sure that resorting to IP tables is the best way to prevent spam on your site, at least if you don't have to block usually annoying IP addresses.

Comment: thanks, my concern is also performance...even if I block the content creation, I still have bots hitting my site over and over...I brought up the ip tables as a way to stop them at the front door to minimize performance impact, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Django CSRF protection is meant to protect your forms from [cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), not from SPAM.

[CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) (Completely Automated Public [Turing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test) test to tell Computers and Humans Apart) will protect you from automated SPAM.

For human generated SPAM you can use a moderation system.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at [django-simple-math-captcha](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-simple-math-captcha/) as an alternative to a text-based captcha. It's very simple to integrate and doesn't rely on any 3rd party systems.

Answer (score 0):

I believe these issues are at the root design issues.  Having a clear policy of who is allowed to post 
can annonymous users post. Perhaps only allow registered users to post.  Or have a set of permissions regarding who is allowed to post where.

Captchas are extremely easy way to weed out spamming.  http://www.google.com/recaptcha 
Recaptcha literally only takes a couple minutes to integrate, and is extremely effective.